# How to resize google maps using iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have the code below in my viewcontroller.m:

```
panoView_ = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 25)];
self.view = panoView_;
[panoView_ moveNearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.732, 150.312)];
```

I want to create a little space at the bottom of the view to place a button in the storyboard but this isn't working as the map (street view) takes up the entire screen. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to appear below the map then use 2 views.one view (`panoViewContainer`) contains a `panoView` and second view (`mainView` - which is self.view) contains `panoViewContainer` and a button below `panoViewContainer`.

```
// Place panoViewContainer in mainView by keeping space for button at bottom,
self.panoViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, (height - spaceForButton));
[self.mainView addSubview:self.panoViewContainer];
self.panoViewContainer = panoView_;

// Place a button in mainView, below panoViewContainer.
[self.mainView addSubview:button];
```